# JMESPath - How to check if key's value is contained in JSON object and return the value if true?

Tags: json, jmespath

I have a contact JSON object like this:

```json
{ "contactType": "Manager", "firstName": "Tom", "lastName": "Jones" }
```

I am trying to query the object like:

```
(contactType=='Manager')
```

to check if the contactType is indeed `Manager`. My question is if the expression is true, how can I return the value, something like `firstName`, from the confirmed Manager object? I know this is easily done with arrays by piping, such as if I had multiple contacts and used:

```
([?contactType=='Manager']|[0].firstName)
```

but how can I achieve the same result checking a singular JSON in a single expression?